# Trying to use an ID in my Style script, but it is not working

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a style script on the same page where my HTML is, where I can add the styling components for this table instead of doing an inline style for each TH. I made an ID for the table, added it to the CSS folder.  However, when I refresh the page, the styling does not appear.  Can someone look at my CSS to see how I have it set up?

```
<table id="table1" style="width:100%; text-align: center; background-color: salmon; border-color: #e9e9e9;">
                @if (PizzaID == 2)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 30%">Charge Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%"></th>
                        <th style="width: 30%">Total Amount</th>
                        <th style="width: 25%">Net</th>
                        <th style="width: 5%"></th>
                    </tr>
                }
                @if (PizzaId == 1)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 30%">Charge Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 10%"></th>
                        <th style="width: 30%">Total</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">Total Incentive</th>
                        <th style="width: 5%">Net</th>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
```

//This is the CSS script I created, which is going below the html.

```
<style>
    #Table, th {
    text-align: center;
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background-color: salmon;  
    border-color: #e9e9e9; 
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The id in your HTML does match the id in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<table id="table1" etc.
```

Your CSS selector:

```
#Table, th { etc.
```

!